# Which manifolds are homeomorphic to simplicial complexes?

Tags: manifolds, simplicial-complexes, gt.geometric-topology, at.algebraic-topology

This question is only motivated by curiosity; I don't know a lot about manifold topology.

Suppose $M$ is a compact topological manifold of dimension $n$.  I'll assume $n$ is large, say $n\geq 4$.  The question is: *Does there exist a simplicial complex which is homeomorphic to $M$?*

What I think I know is:

- If $M$ has a piecewise linear (PL) structure, then it is triangulable, i.e., homeomorphic to a simplicial complex.
- There is a well-developed technology ("[Kirby-Siebenmann invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirby-Siebenmann_invariant)") which tells you whether or not a topological manifold admits a PL-structure.
- There are exotic triangulations of manifolds which don't come from a PL structure.  I think the usual example of this is to take a [homology sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere) $S$ (a manifold with the homology of a sphere, but not maybe not homeomorphic to a sphere), triangulate it, then suspend it a bunch of times.  The resulting space $M$ is supposed to be homeomorphic to a sphere (so is a manifold).  It visibly comes equipped with a triangulation coming from that of $S$, but has simplices whose link is not homemorphic to a sphere; so this triangulation can't come from a PL structure on $M$.

This leaves open the possibility that there are topological manifolds which do not admit *any* PL-structure but are still homeomorphic to some simplicial complex.  Is this  possible?

In other words, what's the difference (if any) between "triangulable" and "admits a PL structure"?

[This Wikipedia page on 4-manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-manifold) claims that the E8-manifold is a topological manifold which is not homeomorphic to any simplicial complex; but the only evidence given is the fact that its Kirby-Siebenmann invariant is non trivial, i.e., it doesn't admit a PL structure.

Comment: Excellent question; I'd like to hear the answer to this too. 

Comment: The fact that the double suspension of a homology sphere is homeo to a  sphere is due to Bob Edwards. It finally appeared (after 30 years!) on the ArXiv in 06
http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0610.5573

Comment: @Paul : That's not quite true.  The double suspension theorem is due to Jim Cannon and was published a 1979 paper entitled "Shrinking cell-like decompositions of manifolds. Codimension three".  Edwards proved a "triple suspension theorem" and also proved the double suspension theorem for many examples, including the Poincare homology 3-sphere.

Comment: @Paul the link in [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44021/which-manifolds-are-homeomorphic-to-simplicial-complexes#comment104912_44021) is broken, here's a replacement: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610573

Comment: Sorry but I am rather confused by all these answers and comments. What is the final conclusion then?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Galewski-Stern proved

https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=420637

" It follows that every topological m-manifold, m≥7 (or m≥6 if ∂M=∅), can be triangulated if and only if there exists a PL homology 3-sphere H3 with Rohlin invariant one such that H3#H3 bounds a PL acyclic 4-manifold."

The Rohlin invariant is a Z/2 valued homomorphsim on the 3-dimensional homology cobordism group, $\Theta_3\to Z/2$, so if it splits there exist non-triangulable manifodls in high dimensions.

Comment: Your answer is about combinatorial triangulations. The question is about arbitrary ones.

Comment: @Igor : Galewski-Stern's theorem is definitely about noncombinatorial triangulations.

Comment: No. "combinatorial triangulation" is synomymous with "PL structure". See the MR.  You are probably mistaking it with the Kirby Siebenmann invariant, which is the obstruction to finding a PL structure on a Topological manifold.

Comment: I take it back, Andy and Paul are right. By the way, the introduction to "The Hauptvermutung Book" explains this all in some detail: See http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/books/haupt.pdf.

Comment: Paul -- I've accidentally stumbled upon this question. Thanks for your answer. Could you please clarify what "a PL acyclic" 4-manifold is.

Comment: I've found the paper. Question settled: a "PL acyclic manifold" is the same as an acyclic PL manifold.

Comment: Yeah, acyclic PL manifold is clearer. 

Comment: Ciprian Manolescu has just posted a paper in which he claims to prove that no such homology 3-sphere exists.

arXiv:1303.2354 
Pin(2)-equivariant Seiberg-Witten Floer homology and the Triangulation Conjecture

Answer (score 33):

I don't know about dimension 4, but for high dimensions this is a well-known open problem.  I don't think much progress has been made on it for a while.  I recommend Ranicki's lecture notes from Siebenmann's retirement conference for a good summary about what is known about this and related problems:
[https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/slides/orsay.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/slides/orsay.pdf)

EDIT : Hot off the press is a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2354) of Manolescu claiming to disprove the conjecture of Galewski-Stern and construct manifolds in all dimensions $\geq 5$ which are not homeomorphic to simplicial complexes.

Comment: Thanks!  Those slides say that the problem is solved in dimension 4 (all manifolds are triangulable), attributed to Casson.

Comment: The slides say (on page 5) that NOT every 4-manifold is triangulable. 

Comment: It seems that the fact that E8 is not triangulable should follow from basic properties of Casson invariant (of which I know next to nothing). I am curious to see how the argument goes. 

Comment: @IB the relationship is explained in Akbulut-McCarthy's book in detail but I've forgotten the argument. There's an outline here 
http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/96/Triangulations
which asserts that if E8 were triangulable it could be smoothed
in the complement of its vertices.  Removing a nbd of each vertex yields a smooth manifold with boundary a union of homotopy (?) 3-spheres whose total  Rohlin invariant is 1 (since $\sigma(E8)=1$).
But Casson's invariant is zero on homotopy spheres and is a lift of Rohlin.

Comment: Ah, I misread it.

Answer (score 10):

Regarding Charles Rezk's second question:

*This leaves open the possibility that there are topological manifolds which do not admit any PL-structure but are still homeomorphic to some simplicial complex. Is this possible?*

For dimension 4, it follows from the Poincare conjecture that a 4-manifold is triangulable iff smoothable (which is also equivalent to having PL structure for dimension <8). See Problem 3 of [Fragments of geometric topology from the sixties](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/haupt/sandro.pdf) by Sandro Buoncristiano. Also see the presentation [From Triangulations to 4-Manifolds: In Honor of Takao Matumoto’s 60<sup>th</sup> Birthday](https://cpb-us-e2.wpmucdn.com/faculty.sites.uci.edu/dist/3/246/files/2011/03/Hiroshima2_18_06.pdf) by Ron Stern.

For dimension >4, [Springer Online Reference Works](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Topology_of_manifolds) claims that "the imbedding $PL \subset TRI$ is also irreversible in the same strong sense (there exist polyhedral manifolds of dimension $\geq 5$ that are homotopy inequivalent to any PL-manifold)",  but gives no examples. In Ron Stern's [presentation](https://cpb-us-e2.wpmucdn.com/faculty.sites.uci.edu/dist/3/246/files/2011/03/Hiroshima2_18_06.pdf) it is stated that "All oriented closed 5-manifolds triangulable", so I think among them there may be some with nontrivial KS invariant and hence cannot bear PL structure.

In addition, the book [Lectures on the Topology of 3-manifolds: An Introduction to the Casson Invariant](https://books.google.com/books?id=gz2CbgR5RbwC) (p.168, Theorem 18.4) by Nikolai Saveliev seems to contain a result that strengthens the one mentioned in Paul's answer.

Added: The paper [Piecewise linear structures on topological manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/math.AT/0105047) (22.5. Example) by Yuli B. Rudyak explicitly gives an example of "A topological manifold which is homeomorphic to a polyhedron but does not admit any PL structure".

Answer (score 7):

For a discussion of the 4-dimensional case see 
http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Questions_about_surgery_theory.